# Add "newbie", "noob" and "n00b" to the question title filter

Tags: feature-request, title

Pretty simple: Add "newbie", "noob" and its variations to the title blacklist / filter, since they have no meaning or relevance to a question.

Specifically:

- [newbie](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Anewbie&submit=search) - **1625** questions
- [noob](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Anoob&submit=search) - **479** questions
- [newb](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Anewb&submit=search) - **97** questions
- [n00b](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3An00b&submit=search) - **38** questions

Based on [Should we edit noob out of titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41860/should-we-edit-noob-out-of-titles), it's already recommended to remove these from titles. So why not let the question filter take care of this for us?

Comment: I don't *necessarily* disagree, but users are already writing `porblem` and `pr0blem` because of a similar filter. Now we'll have `n0ob` and `n00bie` too.

Comment: @Dennis I see what you mean. However, if circumvention is the ultimate problem, then the title filter itself is fundamentally flawed, which is outside of the scope of this feature request. However, since such a filter already exists, adding these to its blacklist *should* (hopefully) reduce the number of posts with this irrelevant garbage in it.

Comment: Arg, why do people talk like this. What a bunch of nubs.

Comment: The title filter's fundamental flaw is its existence. It's impossible to prevent all circumvention, and it limits some legitimate uses of the word.

Comment: I understand - But are there any legitimate uses of noob / its variations? I don't think so, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: For Stack Overflow, not that I know of. But somebody could write a JavaScript library called NewbieScript tommorow, for example. On Super User, there's the [NoobProof firewall configuration tool](http://www.hanynet.com/noobproof/).

Comment: True, but the current filter is restricted to standalone words - "Question" does not pass, but "Questionable" does. So, in the cases where a legitimate name includes "newbie" or "noob", the filter wouldn't trigger.

Comment: What about all the newbies in the world googling "newbie <something> guide" etc.?

Comment: @Dean - For every one of those, there has gotta be 100 people Googling "How to do <something>".